# What is product_options_id refer to?

Tags: bigcommerce

When retrieving a product option one of the fields is product_option_id. I'm confused what it refers to.

```
{"id"=>302,
"product_id"=>2420,
"sku"=>"PRD8675309",
"cost_price"=>"25.0000",
"upc"=>"782519175584",
"inventory_level"=>0,
"inventory_warning_level"=>0,
"bin_picking_number"=>"782519175584",
"options"=>[{"product_option_id"=>169, "option_value_id"=>412}]}
```

The product has options set id 80. 412 is a value of options set 80. What is 169?

Here is snippit of options set. You can see no keys have value 169.

```
[{"id"=>119,
"option_id"=>93,
"option_set_id"=>80,
"display_name"=>"Color Option",
"sort_order"=>0,
"is_required"=>true,
"option"=>
 {"url"=>"ommited",
  "resource"=>"/options/93"},
"values"=>
 [{"label"=>"Black",
   "sort_order"=>0,
   "value"=>"Black",
   "option_value_id"=>410},
  {"label"=>"Chestnut",
   "sort_order"=>1,
   "value"=>"Chestnut",
   "option_value_id"=>412},
  {"label"=>"Holly Leaf",
   "sort_order"=>6,
```

Comment: Have you checked the options-sets with `id` (or possibly `option_id`) with values `169`? I don't know anything about the Bigcommerce platform, but those fields seems like good candidates to check.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the product options themselves as opposed to the product option sets. A set is moreso a reusable set of options, but you want the unique ID of the assigned option itself.